# python unpacking list of tuples

Tags: python, django, list, tuples, unpack

I use python/django, and I have a tuple of tuples (or list of tuples. doesn't really matter), basically it's the output of an SQL query.  I print it like this:

If I have

```
output= [(a1,b1,c1,d1), (a2,b2,c2,d2), ...]
```

So I'll do:

```
for a,b,c,d in output:
  ...
```

now the thing is that sometimes I select a lot of columns and I don't want to print them all.
Can I unpack only the values that I need. or I'm limited because of the order of the tuples?
i.e can I do for example:

```
for a, d in output:
   ...
```

(notice,I want to skip the second and third value in the tuples)
Is that possible or I have to user indexes?

Obviously it is slightly different in django template, but the point is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You still need to unpack them, but you can ignore them:

```
for a, _, _, d in output:
    # Do things with a and d
```

If you are on Python 3 you can also use `*`:

```
for a, *_, d in output:
    # same deal - _ is now a list of all the values between `0 and len(row) - 1`
```

The advantage on Python 3 is that an individual row's length can change (to as low as 2 elements) and you'll still get the right values, whereas in Python 2 the line will break if a row of output is anything other than 4 entries.

Comment: Good enough. is there any difference in terms of efficiency? I mean, is it more efficient not to unpack all the values?

Answer (score 2):

You can't selectively unpack from the tuple. The conventional way to indicate you won't be using certain values in Python is to use an underscore `_`:

```
for a, _, _, d in output:
    ...
```

Alternatively, use the indexes:

```
for t in output:
    a, b = t[0], t[-1]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily the recommended way, but I think there's value in demonstrating how powerful numpy's fancy slicing is:

```
import numpy as np
output = np.array(output, dtype='object')
for a,d in output[:, [0,3]]:
   print('a=%s, d=%s' % (a, d))
```